# filter element of rdd[array[string] by array of [0,1]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to select some elements(feature) of rdd based on binary array. I have an array consisting of `0,1` with size 40 that specify if an element is present at that index or not.

My RDD was created form kddcup99 dataset

```
val rdd=sc.textfile("./data/kddcup.txt")
val data=rdd.map(_.split(','))
```

How can I to filter or select elements of `data(rdd[Array[String]])` whose value of correspondent index in binary array is 1?

Comment: can you share example data and expected output please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you have an array like :

```
val arr =  Array(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

And a `RDD[Array[String]]` which looks like :

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(
              Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F") , 
              Array("G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L") 
           ) )
```

Now, to get elements at the indices where `arr` has 1, you need to first get the indices which have `1` as the value in `arr`

```
val requiredIndices = arr.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 == 1).map(_._2)
requiredIndices: Array[Int] = Array(0, 2, 3, 4)
```

And then similarily with `RDD`, you can use `zipWithIndex` and `contains` to check if that index is available in your `requiredIndices` array :

```
rdd.map(_.zipWithIndex.filter(x => requiredIndices.contains(x._2) ).map(_._1) )  
// Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(A, C, D, E), Array(G, I, J, K))
```

Comment: thanx but i dont understand what is "res9"? is it requiredIndices? when I use requiredIndises instead  of res9 I get this error:Task not serializeble......

Comment: My bad. Yes `res9` is supposed to be `requiredIndices`. I just copied the code from my shell. I'll edit the answer.